# Java JSP/Servlet: how to automatically serve either a .dmg or a .exe file?

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

What is the correct way to automatically serve either a .dmg or a .exe file depending on the OS/browser the user is using to connect to a Java Webapp?

I'd like to do it server side, without having to use any JavaScript.

For example if, from an OS X machine, I go to: [absolute poker](http://www.absolutepoker.com) and click on *"Download & Play"* (it is just an example of a website that has the behavior I'm looking for) it serves me a *.dmg* file that is automatically downloaded by Safari.

I'm looking for a solution that is practical: if it works for 99% of my users I'm happy. I don't care if for some very particular OS/browser combination it doesn't work, as long as "most of the time" Windows users gets served a *.exe* and OS X users a *.dmg*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract it from the `User-Agent` HTTP headr.

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

[Here](http://www.geekpedia.com/code47_Detect-operating-system-from-user-agent-string.html) is a useful resource on how to extract the OS from the User-Agent (it's PHP, but the data is important).

Update: [this](http://user-agent-string.info/) provides a much better way to get info from the user agent. (thanks to BalusC for the link)

Comment: that's a far more useful resource ;)